# Syntax error using MySQL variable in Laravel

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to run the following raw query from Laravel:

```
DB::statement(
    DB::raw("
    SET @lon = ?;
    SET @lat = ?;
    "),
    [$longitude, $latitude],
);
$places = DB::select(
    DB::raw("
    SELECT
    id
    FROM places
    WHERE
          position = POINT(@lon, @lat)
    AND
          language = ?
    AND
          LOWER(name) LIKE LOWER(CONCAT(?, '%'))
    ORDER BY distance
    LIMIT 10;
    "),
    [
        $language,
        $name,
    ],
);
```

The actual query is more complex but it's beyond the scope of the question. Suffice to say that I need `@lon` and `@lat` to be SQL variables.

This gives me the following error:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an
> error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SET @lat = ?'
> at line 2 (SQL: \n            SET @lon = 7.4653;\n            SET @lat
> = 51.5136;\n            )

I had initially tried to put the SET statements inside the same string as the query, but some answers on stack overflow suggested they should be separated. Unfortunately that didn't work, but as far as I can see there isn't any actual error in the syntax, so what is going on?

Comment: what is you MySQL version pls ?

Comment: @HichamO-Sfh 5.7.31.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Laravel Official Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queries#raw-expressions), DB:raw doesn't prevent SQL injection attack so it's not the recommended way what to use it in your case even if you're using SQL parameters/variables...

However I think that neither `DB::statement` nor `DB::raw` does not support multiple queries, so you should separate them :

```
// still a 'risky code' :
DB::statement(DB::raw("SET @lon = ?;",[$longitude]));
DB::statement(DB::raw("SET @lat = ?;",[$latitude]));
```

---

Still the best practice is to use [named bindings](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/database#using-named-bindings)

---

**Edit**

If you still really need to use `DB::raw` and `DB::statement` , then here is a really secured way to use them (combining them with the named binding method ) :

```
// safe code (said by Laravel) :
DB::statement(DB::raw("SET @lon = :longitude;"), ['longitude'=>$longitude]);
DB::statement(DB::raw("SET @lat = :latitude;"), ['latitude'=>$latitude]);
```

Comment: Noted. Is there an easy way to secure the query then?

Comment: yes of course as I've already said, the best practice is to use prepared parameters & named bindings, I've posted direct links to the documentation. glad to help you.

Comment: I have replaced my bindings to be named, but is that enough to prevent SQL injection if $longitude and $latitude come from the request?

Comment: @theberzi I'm not really sur about that, but I have already seen something related to preventing SQLi even when using DB::raw : https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/prevent-sql-injection-in-dbraw

Comment: That solution unfortunately does not apply to my case, because there's (as far as I know) no way to `SET` an SQL variable via a query builder, so I have to use a raw statement.

Comment: @theberzi I have updated my answer, take a look pls.

Comment: Thank you. However, I can't find where the docs mention that using named bindings makes the query safe from SQL injection. All I see is an explanation and example of how to use them, but no mention of security.

Comment: @theberzi Y. Welcome, just read carefully the docs, you will find more informations : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries#introduction

Comment: So in other words, as long as the PDO is taken advantage of, the query is safe. I don't think this depends on whether the binding is positional or named.